# Python module not downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, module, browser-automation

External modules are not getting downloaded in Python. It is showing the below error message for any module that I try to  download.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that you're looking for `pandas` in your work package registry `artifactory.allstate.com`. Since `pandas` is a public package, you need access to the public registry.

Most likely, your pip config is to blame. You'll find your config file at:

- On Linux and macOS: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`
- On Windows: `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`

Do you have `index-url` set?

If so, change the property name to `extra-index-url`. This will add your business registry *in addition to* the public registry.

If you did not find that property, you may be setting your `index-url` config using environment variables.

In similar fashion, you'll want to `unset PIP_INDEX_URL` and `set PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="http://artifactory.allstate.com/..."`.

Just make sure you use the same value you had before, but change the property.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great answer to a low-context question. Good content for those Googling, :). Now only if the OP's error was text, not an image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mike and sorry for the delayed response . But I was not able find "%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini". I tried some other ways with a friend but in the end I connected with a python guy from work. A simple commad - "set NO_PROXY = artifactory.allstate.com" helped me download external modules.